# How to add a frame around a float with caption?

Tags: floats, mdframed, framed

I've created a new float element to define examples:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{example}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{example}{\textsc{Example}}
```

I want to set my example in an frame. Usually I use the `mdframed` or `framed` environment to set figures in frames.

The current problem is that I can't wrap my example with the caption. I can only wrap the example.

```
\begin{example}
    \begin{mdframed}{
        My example
        \caption{content of the caption}
    }
    \end{mdframed}
\end{example}
```

Is there a way to set the example and the caption in a frame like with a figure or a table ?

With a minimal example to see the difference between a *figure* and my *example* :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{example}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{example}{\textsc{Example}}

\begin{document}

% The figure
\begin{figure}
    \begin{mdframed}{
        My figure
        \caption{content of the caption}
    }
    \end{mdframed}
\end{figure}

%The example
\begin{example}
    \begin{mdframed}{
        My example
        \caption{content of the caption}
    }
    \end{mdframed}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my own MWE, rather than building on yours.  I create the figure content, with a `\captionof` caption, and place it in a temporary `\vbox`.  Then I place a frame around the recalled `\vbox`.  I need the `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}` construct, since the framed box is now wider than `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,xcolor,graphicx,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\setbox0=\vbox{
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}
\captionof{figure}{xyz}
}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\makebox[\textwidth]{\fboxrule=2pt\textcolor{red}{\fbox{\box0}}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `tcolorbox`.

A new kind of float (`example`) is declared with `float` and also a framed environment for it (`texample`). This one is made with a floating `tcolorbox` (`float` option). It's floating position is controlled with `floatplacement` option, which by default is `htb`. The caption is added with `\captionof{example}{...}` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{texample}[1][]{float, notitle, #1}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{example}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{example}{\textsc{Example}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]


\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{content of the caption}
\end{figure}


\begin{texample}[floatplacement=t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
        \captionof{example}{content of the caption}
\end{texample}

\begin{texample}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
        \captionof{example}{content of the caption}
\end{texample}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The aim is also to have the `Example 1` instead of `Figure 1`. I want to differentiate the two elements.

Comment: @Klapmox I've updated the answer to distinguish between both environments.

Comment: @thibaut-guirimand this may help : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581645/28926