# Floating textbox with figure, figure caption is outside of box when using package "caption"

Tags: floats, captions, mdframed

Hei,

I am trying to add a textbox to my document. The textbox should contain both text and one or more figures, and should be floating itself.
It works, as long as I do not include the caption package. However, as soon as I use the caption package, the caption of the figure is moved outside the box. Any ideas? Bug in package caption? Something I missed? Or a good alternative for defining floating textboxes with figures?

Thanks, Theo

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,float}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdtheorem{boxtest}{Box}[section]
\newfloat{floatbox}{tb}{abox}[section]
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\section{First}
Figure \ref{fig:test} is in Box \ref{box:test}.

\begin{floatbox}[b!]
    \begin{boxtest}[Testbox]
        \label{box:test}    

        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Highly precise description of the example image: it is an A.}
            \label{fig:test}
        \end{figure}

        \lipsum[1]
    \end{boxtest}
\end{floatbox}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248370/how-to-add-a-frame-around-a-float-with-caption it looks exactly like what you're asking for.

Comment: No, didnt see it and also did not answer my question.

Comment: Why did it not answer your question? Explain it please!

Comment: Read the questions, please! Both the question and the answer are different. I want to put both text and a figure with a caption into a box with a counter. That is different from framing a figure. I needed the \restylefloat, which was not proposed in the other answer.
It may have been possible to extend the other answer to my problem, but I honestly dont know how.
If you insist on calling this a duplicate, I dont care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,float}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdtheorem{boxtest}{Box}[section]
\newfloat{floatbox}{tb}{abox}[section]
\restylefloat*{floatbox}% <-----------------
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

    \section{First}
    Figure \ref{fig:test} is in Box \ref{box:test}.

    \begin{floatbox}[b!]
        \begin{boxtest}[Testbox]
            \label{box:test}    

            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
                \caption{Highly precise description of the example image: it is an A.\label{fig:test}}
            \end{figure}

            \lipsum[1]
        \end{boxtest}
    \end{floatbox}
    \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

You'll need to use `\restylefloat*{floatbox}` to prevent it from taking over the `\caption` command within the figure environment, i.e., so that `\caption` in figure still remains a figure caption instead of becoming a floatbox caption.

---

### Sample output

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the fast reply. But I must admit that I do not quite understand the technicalities of this. Anyway, works like a charm