# float package: how to define new floatstyle to include caption within box frame - limited environment, only limited package available

Tags: floats

I am using following code to get a frame around my figure globally

```
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Figure example with frame}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{exampleimagefile}
\end{figure}
```

like below:

[image]

Just wondering how can I change the position of caption into the box?

[image]

I am using a limited server environment, so only the following packages can be used:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{textboxBack}{HTML}{fac090}
\definecolor{textboxBoder}{HTML}{e46c0a}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}
\floatplacement{table}{H}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf,textfont=bf,font=small,skip=5pt}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,textfont=bf,font=small}
\usepackage{geometry}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you complete your minimal example and make it compilable, please?

Comment: @CarLaTeX example code edited.Thanks

Comment: I think the accepted answer to this question: [How to add a frame around a float with caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248370/how-to-add-a-frame-around-a-float-with-caption) is an answer to your question.

Comment: @corporal the post you mentioned is different from my environment. The main difference is the figure is generated by R on the fly, not simply as the minimal example I provided by using \includegraphics. So I only can change the global setting of {figure} object, and I only have float package to use, so the solution needs to be the modification of the setting of \floatstyle{boxed} to include caption. maybe my question can be renamed as how to define a new floatstyle based on {boxed}

Comment: @lpfy: Can you use the [`environ` package](//ctan.org/pkg/environ)?

Answer (score 2):

Use `\restylefloat*{figure}` instead of `\restylefloat{figure}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat*{figure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{exampleimagefile}
  \caption{Figure example with frame}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As opposite to `\restylefloat`, the starred variant `\restylefloat*` leaves the original captioning code intact, and as result the caption will be part of the box here.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will suit your requirements. The code is borrowed and adapted from the TeXbook. You can explicitly set `\floatstyle{plain}` or simply remove `\floatstyle{boxed}`. I don't know if this will suit your working environment of using R on the fly.

```
\newcommand{\boxit}[1]{\medskip\moveleft3.4pt\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\vrule\kern3pt%
\vbox{\kern-5pt#1\kern-5pt}\kern3pt\vrule}\hrule}}

\boxit{\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure example with frame}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{exampleimagefile}
\end{figure}}
```