# Remove space after \captionof

Tags: floats, captions, tcolorbox

I'm trying to embed a picture and its caption inside a tcolorbox with a special layout.
Indeed, the caption has to be placed in the "frame" made around the picture.

I've found decent examples here, and I managed to get 90% of what I'm trying to have.
I've made a bicolor tcolorbox with the image in the upper part and the caption in the lower part, using the `\captionof` macro.

However, an extra space is placed after the caption.
If I replace the caption by some static text I don't have this problem.

I've search the documentation of the package, and the option `\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}` doesn't have any effect.

How can I reduce the space produced by the `captionof` macro ?

[image: MWE output]

Here is the MWE :

```
\usepackage[svgnames,usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{texample}[1][]{float, notitle, #1}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{example}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{example}{\textsc{Figure}}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{texample}[bicolor,sharp corners,
    colback=white,colframe=gray!20,colbacklower=gray!20,
    top=1mm,bottom=1mm,middle=1mm]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\tcblower
\captionof{example}{Caption content, notice the big space that I'm trying to remove}
\end{texample}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is sometimes confusing to distinguish between `aboveskip` and `belowskip` because their meaning sometimes change according to the value of `position`. It is discussed in section 2.6 of `caption`'s [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption). To avoid confusion in a case like this, it might be better to set `skip` to zero.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{texample}[1][]{float, notitle, #1}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{example}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{example}{\textsc{Figure}}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{texample}[bicolor,sharp corners,
    colback=white,colframe=gray!20,colbacklower=gray!20,
    top=1mm,bottom=1mm,middle=1mm]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\tcblower
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\captionof{example}{Caption content}
\end{texample}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to this particular question but an alternative construction for what I understand OP wants.

OP wants to embed a image into a `tcolorbox` whith a `caption` as title but with this title below the image instead of usual upper position in `tcolorboxes`.

`tcolorbox` package has some commands to declare `floating` boxes and include them into the list of figures or whatever float. In this case the title starts with `Figure ...` like any regular caption. Furthermore, `flip title` option allows to place the title box below the box content. This way it's not necesary to use a `bicolor` box and `captionof` package to construct the captions.

Here you have an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{texfigure}[2][]{%
    float, sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=gray!20, 
    enhanced, coltitle=black, halign title=center, flip title={sharp corners, colback=gray!20}, before upper={\centering}, title={#2}, #1}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{texfigure}{This is the caption}
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{texfigure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For integration constraints, in my code the caption always comes **after** the picture itself, and thus I can't make your example compatible :/